# Visual Express : SDL_Image is undefined

Tags: c++, sdl

I just installed SDL_Image for use in my Visual Studio. And I keep getting any command related to SDL_Image as undefined. I have been following this tutorial

`http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php`

And according to the tutorial, it is Step 11 that is the cause. I have compared the tutorial's version to my own

```
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib
SDL2_image.lib
```

And apart from the lack of SDL2_ttf.lib and SDL2_mixer.lib, I can't see a real difference that would effect it. I have checked that my .dlls are in the correct place and from the correct .zips and folders. I can't see anything else that would cause the problem. Perhaps I missed something. What else can produce the "**_** is undefined" error?

I have just checked the tutorial again and made sure that the tutorial has been followed correctly.

Comment: Are you including SDL_image.h where you use functions from SDL_image?

Comment: Yes. It is right under where the #include <SDL.h> is in the same document as the main. By the time it would be used the SDL should be up and running

Comment: Are you linking against the correct version of the library, ie x86 or x64? (And are you using the matching DLL?) It might be helpful if you post the entire error message you're getting.

Comment: I made sure of it this time (x86 and x64 wise). Below is the full error

`Error 1 error C3861: 'IMG_Load': identifier not found c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\game.cpp 13 1 Project1`

This is the error. IntelliSense says it is 'IMG_load is undefined'

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually happens when you incorrectly set the include path in your project properties, adjust it so the path is similar to this : C:\\SDL\include

If the issue still persists, try seeing if the linker libs path is incorrect.

comment your progress and ill edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I'll put the directories below
`Include -> C:\vs_dev_lib\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0;$(IncludePath)`
`Lib -> C:\vs_dev_lib\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0;$(LibraryPath)`

Perhaps I am missing a file? What files MUST be in the include and lib folders?